# AttributeError: It says builtin_function_or_method has no attribution"shape", but it's not

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(4,4,12)) 
layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=FILTERS1+FILTERS2+FILTERS3, kernel_size=(2,2), 
                 padding="same", activation=None, 
                 kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(1e-4))(input)
```

What makes this wrong?
This is not builtin_function_or_method.

Comment: `input` **is** a `builtin_function_or_method`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `layer=`, change `input` to `inputs`, which you defined in the first line (`inputs =`).

`input` is a built-in Python method for requesting user input. You could override it via `input =`, but that's not recommended.